# Migrate the single file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have migration files for existing database but I need to add new migration file for new table but when I run the command migrate It tells me the older tables already exist .. so How can I run single migration file ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that you ran a rollback previously and it had some error in the code or did not drop the table. This still however messes up the laravel migration table.

You need to run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

if that also fails just go in and drop all the tables which you may have to do as it seems your migration table is messed up.

another trick would be,

run your migrations on a new empty database,and copy the migration table content from that database to your database.